# Prove a function is not uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Use the definition of uniform continuity to prove the function G(x) = x^3 is not uniformly on [0, infinity).

Comment: Do you understand why the function is not uniformly continuous? What have you tried? Would the statement be true on $[0,a]$? Or $[0,a)$?
Hint #2: Let $\epsilon = 1$. Given $\delta > 0$, find $x$ such that $|x^3 - y^3| \geq 1$ even though $|x-y| < \delta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Equivalent sequential Criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Characterization_via_sequences) for Uniform continuity is violated by taking

$x_n=n+{1\over n},y_n=n, \text{Then} (x_n-y_n)\to 0\text {but } f(x_n)-f(y_n)\nrightarrow  0$